# Make Angular checkbox unselect

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have requirement where from array i have to create list of checkbox using classes.now again one reset button will be there after clicking on that all selection will be reseted , how to do that thanks

```
    $scope.classList=['Class1','Class2','Class3','Class4'];
$scope.selectedClasses={};
    $scope.selectedClasses.usall=false;
    $scope.selectedClasses.sall=false;          
    $scope.selectedClasses.classListchecked=false;
    $scope.getSubscribedClassList = function(classNam) {

            if(classNam==="All"){
                 $scope.selectedClasses.usall=false;
                 $scope.selectedClasses.classListchecked=false;
            }


                else{
                    $scope.selectedClasses.usall=false;
                    $scope.selectedClasses.sall=false;
                    $scope.selectedClasses.classListchecked.push(classNam)

            }
        }
```

Below is my fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/alokranjan39/49cc14yk/38/

Answer (score 0):

I have made few changes in your fiddle (forked it here - http://jsfiddle.net/9Lv8gdr3/1/)

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="masterSelect" ng-click="getSubscribedClassList('All')"> UnSelectAll

  <li ng-repeat="class in classList">
    <span>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.isSelected" ng-disabled="class.students.length==0">
                                                    {{class.name}} </span>
  </li>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.classList = [{
    isSelected: false,
    name: 'Class1'
  }, {
    isSelected: false,
    name: 'Class2'
  }, {
    isSelected: false,
    name: 'Class3'
  }, {
    isSelected: false,
    name: 'Class4'
  }];

  $scope.getSubscribedClassList = function(classNam) {

    if (classNam === "All") {
      angular.forEach($scope.classList, function(value, index) {       
        value.isSelected = $scope.masterSelect;       
      });
    } else {
      //you dont ideally need this. get the items with isSelected === true from $scope.classList to get the checked items

    }
  };
}
```

To get the list of selected item, just loop through the `$scope.classList` and get the items for which `isSelected === true`

Comment: i dont want to change array

Answer (score 0):

Updated your fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/49cc14yk/43/

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedClasses" ng-click="getSubscribedClassList()">
    UnSelectAll                 

    <li ng-repeat="class in classList">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="class.value">
                {{class.label}}
        </span>
    </li>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.classList=[{
        label: 'Class1', value: false
    }, {
        label: 'Class2', value: false
    }, {
        label: 'Class3', value: false
    }, {
        label: 'Class4', value: false
    }];

    $scope.getSubscribedClassList = function() {
      $scope.classList.forEach(function(obj) {
          obj.value = $scope.selectedClasses;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: i dont want to change array

Comment: You don't want to change the array? But then, where you will store the selected checkbox? the ng-model don't work as you created.

Answer (score 0):

Have updated fiddle for array also - http://jsfiddle.net/49cc14yk/45/

HTML :

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectAll" ng-click="getSubscribedClassList('ALL')">
    UnSelectAll                 
    <li ng-repeat="class in classList">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" name="selectedClasses[]" value="{{class}}"
            ng-checked="selectedClassList.indexOf(class) > -1" ng-click="getSubscribedClassList(class)">
            {{class}}
        </span>
    </li>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.classList = ['Class1','Class2','Class3','Class4'];
    // Initialise below array as per your requirement, maybe blank
    $scope.selectedClassList = ['Class1','Class2'];

    $scope.getSubscribedClassList = function(value) {
        if(value == 'ALL') {
            $scope.selectedClassList = [];
            if($scope.selectAll) {
                $scope.selectedClassList = Object.create($scope.classList);
            }
        } else {
            var idx = $scope.selectedClassList.indexOf(value);
            if (idx > -1) {
                $scope.selectedClassList.splice(idx, 1);
            } else {
                $scope.selectedClassList.push(value);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Using as object is more appropriate so keeping that answer too